# find query returning empty array with variable,But giving result when actual value is passed as a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, mongoose-schema

I am trying to get result from my database collection on mongoDB clusters through email Id.

CODE:

```
app.post("/home",function(req,res){

    const questionNo=req.body.questionNo;

    const givenAnswer=req.body.answer;
    const userEmailId=req.body.userEmail;
    if(userEmailId===req.body.userEmail){
        console.log("True")
    }
    else{
        console.log("false");
    }
    credential.find({emailId:userEmailId},function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(result);
        }

    })

});
```

But it is showing the null result

> OUTPUT: Server started on port 3000 True []

But when I put value as a string instead of using email id variable,

CODE:

```
app.post("/home",function(req,res){

    const questionNo=req.body.questionNo;
    const givenAnswer=req.body.answer;
    const userEmailId=req.body.userEmail;
    const id=userEmailId;
    if(userEmailId===req.body.userEmail){
        console.log("True")
    }
    else{
        console.log("false");
    }
    credential.find({emailId:"pshrimal000@gmail.com"},function(err,result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log(result);
        }

    })
});
```

> OUTPUT:
>
> Server started on port 3000
>
> True
>
> [   {
>       _id: 5ee0811c7a765025a4d4cb83, 
>       firstName: 'Ashutosh', 
>       lastName: 'Shrimal', 
>       emailId: 'pshrimal000@gmail.com', 
>       currentQuestion: '1', 
>       __v: 0   } ]

Comment: Have you tried to log the `req.body.userEmail` before executing the query. Just do a `console.log(req.body.userEmail)` and make sure you are getting a proper emailId

Comment: yes that is proper. I even tried the value given by userEmail in find.

Comment: Okay. Just try with `trim()` to make sure there is no whitespace at both ends of the emailId. `credential.find({emailId:userEmailId.trim()`}...`

Comment: Great! It worked! Thanks a lot! There was a whitespace which i think was because of <input> with hidden type.